# SFDX auth login is throwing an error "Windows cannot find error opening a https://login.salesforce... Make sure you typed the name correctly"

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli

[image: *enter image description here*]

When I try to login to Dev Hub using this command in the terminal:

```
sfdx force:auth:web:login --setdefaultdevhubusername --setalias NewDevHub
```

I encountered an error as shown in the picture above.

I'm using a Windows 10 64-bit computer with a sfdx-cli version of 6.44.0.
My default browser is Internet Explorer 11.

Can anyone please help me? Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87769/discussion-on-question-by-raniel-agno-sfdx-auth-login-is-throwing-an-error-wind).

Comment: I'm also having this issue, does anyone have a solution?  The conversation link above is pointed to a page not found.

Answer (score 0):

If you go into your computer settings and verify the default browser is set it should work.  I would reset your default browser to verify.